# Why does sqlalchemy takes longer time to execute a query than using mysql client?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a query like this:

> select max(id), min(id) from MY_TABLE where create_date >= '2022-01-01' and create_date < '2022-01-02'

When I use MySQL Workbench to run this SQL, it use about 250 second. But when I use sqlalchemy with python, this query is stuck, I wait for more than 1 hour and it didn't return any result. I think my code is right because other small query can be executed. My code is like:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, connect_args={"ssl": ssl_context})
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text(sql))
```

What should I do? What params should I check?

Comment: Have you tried BETWEEN?

Comment: Are you sure the table isn't locked?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I check the lock status and found the table is locked, but I've already set `isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT'`, should I change it to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this. My script was connected to the master server of MySQL, which cannot modify `isolation_level` and had many write operation executing. Workbench was connected to the read server, so it's faster for query.